# remove a specific part from url with htaccess and redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was using translatepress on my WordPress site so my site URLs were like `example.com/en-ae/hair-transplant` but now I have removed translatepress so now my URLs are like `example.com/hair-transplant` but I have submitted URLs for SEO with the `en-ae` slug. I want that if `en-ae` is present in any URL then it gets removed automatically and gets redirected to page without `en-ae`.

For example `example.com/en-ae/hair-transplant` redirects to `example.com/hair-transplant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *remove* the `/en-ae` prefix from all requested URLs (to help preserve SEO), you would need to add the following near the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker):

```
# Remove "/en-ae/" prefix from all requests
RewriteRule ^en-ae/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, which already occurs *later* in the file (in the WordPress code block).

The `R=301` flag triggers an external "permanent" redirect - without which the URL-prefix is not actually removed. However, you should first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

The slash prefix on the *substitution* string is necessary to avoid a malformed redirect, if the `RewriteBase` directive is omitted from the WordPress code block.

Answer (score 0):

You need the rewrite module of Apache: *mod_rewrite*.

Then in your htaccess this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^en-ae/(.*)$ $1
```

Comment: Not sure how this "worked perfectly"? As written this doesn't "redirect", it's an internal rewrite (which won't work with WordPress or help with SEO). You would need the `R=301` and `L` flags to issue a permanent redirect. But you will also need the slash prefix on the _substitution_ string  (or rely on the `RewriteBase` directive which is usually set elsewhere in the WordPress code block). @MuhammadSufyan

Comment: hello MRWHITE. it actually didn't work. it worked only for parent pages but not for inner pages. can you please share complete code?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /en-ae/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

```
#Condition base redirection
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ae/(en|ar)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ae/(.*)$ https://www.siteurl.com/ae/en/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kw/(en|ar)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^kw/(.*)$ https://www.siteurl.com/kw/en/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```